# How to clone a non-generic List?

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have problem with cloning a list which is not a generic one.

In WPF, I have a property `MyListView.SelectedItems` which is an `IList`, non-generic list.

I want to clone it but I have no such extensions like for generic list.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

```
var collection = new ArrayList(yourIList);
```

Comment: @SnakeEyes please note - this only copies the reference of the items, not make new copies of them.